# Go lang : running routine on different process

Tags: go

I want to run a 3 go routine on different process. Upon research I found that I need to use runtime.GOMAXPROCS(). But even after using runtime.GOMAXPROCS(), all routine runs on same process. How can I make it run on different process. Below is the code and output. Here is the link to [goplayground](https://play.golang.org/p/h-wDcha200)

```
func main() {

    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)

    fmt.Printf("Number of CPU %d \n",runtime.NumCPU())

    fmt.Printf("Process id of main %d \n\n",os.Getpid())


    for i:=0 ;i<3; i++{
        go printAndSleep(i)
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 100)

}

func printAndSleep(i int){
    for {
        fmt.Printf("Process id of %d go routine %d \n",i,os.Getpid())
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    }   
}
```

Output :

```
Number of CPU 8 
Process id of main 16874 

Process id of 0 go routine 16874 
Process id of 2 go routine 16874 
Process id of 1 go routine 16874 
Process id of 0 go routine 16874 
Process id of 1 go routine 16874 
Process id of 2 go routine 16874 
Process id of 0 go routine 16874 
Process id of 1 go routine 16874 
Process id of 2 go routine 16874 
Process id of 2 go routine 16874 
Process id of 0 go routine 16874 
Process id of 1 go routine 16874
```

Here you can see all the routine runs on same process even though I have used GOMAXPROCS . Why is that? Am I using it wrong

Comment: Running goroutines are multiplexed across a maximum of GOMAXPROCS OS threads. There is only ever one process.

Comment: Thanks @JimB but Is there a way to check the difference in GOMAXPROCS(1) and GOMAXPROCS(2) like a running id or something?

Comment: Go is designed for concurency not parallelism. Thus, Go runtime decides how routines are executed, and that's the power of Go. That means you have no reason to decide it yourself (not in Go). If you google "Concurrency is not parallelism" you'll find some talk about Go concurrency design.

Comment: @TheLion: The difference between `GOMAXPROCS(1)` and `GOMAXPROCS(2)` is 1 os thread for running user goroutines vs 2. That is all. What is it you want to check? Goroutines aren't pinned to a particular thread unless you call `runtime.LockOSThread()`, but there's really very few reasons to do that.

Answer (score -1):

If you want only one goroutine running on each process, you can use [runtime.LockOSThread()](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread) to make a 1:1 relation between process and goroutines running on that process. In your case, you should invoke runtime.LockOSThread every time you launch a new goroutine.

```
for i:=0 ;i<3; i++{
    go func(){
        runtime.LockOSThread()
        printAndSleep(i)
    }()
}
```